# Proper-Casing Street names in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

With the application that I am working with and writing reports for, the user is entering the Location in all upper case. It has been requested by those who my reports are going to that the Location be in proper case. This was fine till I realized that proper case does not recognize abbreviations. Is there a way to write an expression in SSDT that will, while converting the street name into proper case, also make is so abbreviations like "SE" or "DR" are upper case?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I updated my question. I apologize for the mix up.

Comment: I can't imagine there's a simple way to do this. You'd be better off fixing the data at the source. There are data cleansing services and APIs which can do this sort of thing, by having a deep understanding of what an address looks like, and by matching against postal service data. This is the sort of thing to do when the data are entered, not when it is reported.

Comment: Alright, is there a way to make the data entered into a WPF application be stored in the format I would like?

Answer (score 0):

John Saunders is right, it's not simple, and it'd be better if you can fix the data at the source.   But you can wrap your Proper Case function in a series of outer REPLACE Functions.  It's not simple because you'll have to analyze your data and figure out all the abbreviations you want to handle, and manually code each one.   It will get huge, so you might consider creating this function in SSRS custom code, so it doesn't look so cluttered in the expression builder.

Psuedo code would look something like this:

```
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    ProperCase(MyFieldName)
  ,"Se","SE")
,"Dr","DR")
```

Add a REPLACE(InnerExpression,ProperCaseExpression,UpperCaseExpression) for each individual abbreviation you want to handle.   It won't be fun, but it will work.